# Setup Wi-Fi's Proxy on Ubuntu os

Tags: wireless, proxy, settings

Ok, on my school's wi-fi, it requires proxy to be setup, so I am asking if there is a way to setup a proxy on ubuntu's wifi settings, is there?

Answer (score 2):

You can do that in the system configuration under network

system settings > network > proxy

[image: settings]

**In case you need set by hand your proxy:**

[image: network]

**If your school uses a auto configuration proxy file:**

[image]